# How to move project .netcore in visual studio to run on windows from mac

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

First i start project .netcore 2.2 in my mac pro.
And then i want to move it to dev on windows
But in visual studio on windows show error below And can not update package. seem like it can not find path in mac How can i fix it and can run this project on windows? And make it can run any os.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
>   NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder '/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder'.
>      at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders)

Comment: Looks like you moved too much, also copying the obj subdirectory.  There is a .json file there that remembers the macOS directory.  Delete by hand to get ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the bin/ and obj/ directories and build again.